# Can applications on the shell activities overview show icons?

Tags: gnome-shell, activities-overview

This is the gnome activities overview [image]

It's kinds slow reading through or looking for applications that look very similar. Anyone know of a way to show icons alongside the names? It's much faster to look for icons

Answer (score 5):

There is [a GitHub repository](https://github.com/sustmi/gnome-shell-extensions-sustmi) with a Gnome-shell extenstions that seems to do what you are looking for (although I haven't tried it). Install it using:

```
git clone https://github.com/sustmi/gnome-shell-extensions-sustmi.git
mv gnome-shell-extensions-sustmi/windowoverlay-icons ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/windowoverlay-icons@sustmidown.centrum.cz
```

The source, including a screenshot, of this post can be found [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/2-more-gnome-shell-extensions-cpu.html).

Comment: Clicking through shows that the linked plugin has been deprecated and points you to 'WindowOverlay Icons' as seen in the other answer.

Answer (score 5):

### [WindowOverlay Icons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/302/windowoverlay-icons/)

> Add application icons to window overview

**Installation:**

- Install gnome-tweaks

  ```
  sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
  ```
- Click on the title above and turn the switch on

**Extension Homepage:**  https://github.com/sustmi/gnome-shell-extension-windowoverlay-icons

[image]